# python 2.7 in Ubuntu can't find package even those it is installed in other location

Tags: ubuntu, python, pip

i get this error : `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/responsetypes/mime.types'` and indeed this location does not exist but this lib in instaled (i installed via pip) in usr location : `/usr/local/scrapy/core/downloader/responsetypes/mime.types` how can i change python configuration so that python 2.7 will find his packages (i am not using venv) 
also i have another computer to compare with, the main difference seems to me is the location of the python packages - needs to `be Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` but instead it is `/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` how can i change this prefix?

, in the working computer :

```
pip show scrapy
Name: Scrapy
Version: 0.9
Summary: A high-level Python Screen Scraping framework
Home-page: http://scrapy.org
Author: Pablo Hoffman
Author-email: pablo@pablohoffman.com
License: BSD
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requires: Twisted
Required-by:
```

and in the trouble computer :

```
 pip show scrapy
    ---
    Metadata-Version: 2.0
    Name: Scrapy
    Version: 0.9
    Summary: A high-level Python Screen Scraping framework
    Home-page: http://scrapy.org
    Author: Pablo Hoffman
    Author-email: pablo@pablohoffman.com
    Installer: pip
    License: BSD
    Location: /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    Requires: Twisted
    Classifiers:
      Programming Language :: Python
      Programming Language :: Python :: 2.5
      Programming Language :: Python :: 2.6
      Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7
      License :: OSI Approved :: BSD License
      Operating System :: OS Independent
      Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable
      Intended Audience :: Developers
      Environment :: Console
      Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries :: Application Frameworks
      Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries :: Python Modules
      Topic :: Internet :: WWW/HTTP
```

Answer (score 0):

Scrapy Python web scraping and crawling framework (Python 3) is provided by the default Ubuntu repositories in  Ubuntu 18.04 and later. To install it open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install python3-scrapy
```

If Scrapy is installed in this way, Ubuntu will not have any trouble finding it. Python 2.x is not installed by default in Ubuntu 18.04 and later, so if you install python3-scrapy in Ubuntu 18.04 and later you will have an easier time using it.

Comment: i want to install scrapy for python not scrapy cmd , maybe with the added info it will be easier to help